# The area of the range of a bounded analytic complex function of a complex variable.

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is the area of a bounded analytic complex function of a complex variable equal to the double integral of the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of the mapping for that function, for the domain under consideration?

Comment: only for univalent functions - or otherwise considering the area in a general multiple coverings sense (see $z^2$ on the closed disc); for univalent functions, it is just the usual change of variable formula and the Jacobian is $|f'(z)|^2$

Comment: Thank you, I was really looking for an explicitly geometric explanation relating the area, to that change of variable formula.

Comment: the only thing I would suggest is looking at the stretch of the area element $dx \wedge dy$ under $f$ and convince yourself that is indeed the Jacobian

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that.